# The Flutter Cupertino app tutorial seems to be broken

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm stuck at step 6 of the tutorial at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-cupertino/#5.  I cannot understand what it is complaining about.

[image: errors]

If I tried to reload the app or do run the program again, the console shows different errors:

```
$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...

Compiler message:
lib/product_list_tab.dart:25:39: Error: Not a constant expression.
                          if (index < products.length) {
                                      ^^^^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:25:31: Error: Not a constant expression.
                          if (index < products.length) {
                              ^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:27:38: Error: Not a constant expression.
                              index: index,
                                     ^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:28:49: Error: Not a constant expression.
                              product: products[index],
                                                ^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:28:40: Error: Not a constant expression.
                              product: products[index],
                                       ^^^^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:29:50: Error: Not a constant expression.
                              lastItem: index == products.length - 1,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:29:41: Error: Not a constant expression.
                              lastItem: index == products.length - 1,
                                        ^^^^^
lib/product_list_tab.dart:24:25: Error: Not a constant expression.
                        (context, index) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is it a problem with the tutorial or am I missing something?

Comment: I got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue.
Try to change `slivers: const <Widget>[` to `slivers: <Widget>[`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `const` from `return CustomScrollView(` fixed it for me.

```
  final products = model.getProducts();
  return CustomScrollView( // <--- here
    semanticChildCount: products.length,
    slivers: <Widget>[
```